# How to declare an array of ui.NewEntry?

Tags: user-interface, go, andlabs-ui

I am trying to create a GUI with a series of text entry fields:

```
package main
import ("github.com/andlabs/ui")
func main() {
    ui.Main(makeMainWin)
}
func makeMainWin(){
    var entlist = []ui.NewEntry //Error here. How to declare an array of ui.NewEntry?
    var box = ui.NewVerticalBox()
    for i,_ := range [5]int{} {
        println(i)
        box.Append(ui.NewEntry(), false)
    }
    var mainWindow = ui.NewWindow("Hello", 200, 100, false)
    mainWindow.SetChild(box)
    mainWindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { 
               ui.Quit(); return true   } )
    mainWindow.Show()
}
```

However, there is error on `var entlist = []NewEntry`

I am not able to create an array of NewEntry components. I have tried `[]ui.NewEntry`, `[]*ui.NewEntry`, `[]ui.NewEntry()` and `[]*ui.NewEntry()`

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `NewEntry` is a function, you can't make an array of a function.

Comment: Also none of the things you listed are [arrays](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6), they are all [slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui.NewEntry` returns `*Entry`, therefore your slice should be declared as:

```
var entlist []*ui.Entry
```